# I got error #1064 while making a database table with Foreign key

Tags: database, foreign-keys, project, mysql-error-1064

I'm making a table for my school project and got a #1064 error on line 2

```sql
CREATE TABLE markah (
   kodKursus int(4),
   FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES kursus(kodKursus),
   kodAkaun int(4) not null,
   FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES akaun(kodAkaun),
   jumlahMarkah int(10) not null,
   jumlahJawabBetul int(10) not null,
   jumlahJawabKesalahan int(10) not null,
   jumlahMasaGuna time(6) not null,
   FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES masa(jumlahMasaGuna),
   kodItemDapat int(4),
   FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES item(kodItemDapat)
);
```

Comment: idk why my post looks like that, they don't let me post image too

Comment: You should wrap your code with ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the foreign key on every `FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES`. Modify the following according to your needs:

```sql
CREATE TABLE markah (
  kodKursus int(4),
  FOREIGN KEY (foreignKeyToComplete) REFERENCES kursus(kodKursus),
  kodAkaun int(4) not null,
  FOREIGN KEY (foreignKeyToComplete) REFERENCES akaun(kodAkaun),
  jumlahMarkah int(10) not null,
  jumlahJawabBetul int(10) not null,
  jumlahJawabKesalahan int(10) not null,
  jumlahMasaGuna time(6) not null,
  FOREIGN KEY (foreignKeyToComplete) REFERENCES masa(jumlahMasaGuna),
  kodItemDapat int(4),
  FOREIGN KEY (foreignKeyToComplete) REFERENCES item(kodItemDapat)
);
```